# PreProcessor in Oracle External Tables

Tags: oracle, external-tables

I seem to be having an issue whenever I add the preprocessor clause into my external tables statement. Without the preprocessor line it all works fine but as soon as I add it I get assorted errors depending on where I put it in the access parameters block, do they have to be in a particular order? I can't find any similar issues online.

Edit: Also as a side note, I know you can use preprocessor to feed in a zipped file to the external table. If I want to read a zipped file AND append the filename is it as easy as just putting it all in the one shell file?

```
CREATE TABLE (
    column1 VARCHAR2(40),
    column2 VARCHAR2(40)
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
(
  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
  DEFAULT DIRECTORY DMPDIR
    ACCESS PARAMETERS(
        RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
        LOGFILE DMPDIR:'test.log'
        BADFILE DMPDIR:'test.bad'
        fields terminated by '^'
        MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
        REJECT ROWS WITH ALL NULL FIELDS
        preprocessor DMPDIR: 'append_filename.sh'
    )
 LOCATION (DMPDIR: 'testfile.dat')
);
```

append_filename.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -e 's!$!,'"${1##*/}"'!' $1
```

Comment: Are we supposed to guess the errors? Are we supposed to guess your Oracle version?

Comment: Oracle 11.2.0.3.0 so supports pre-processor I believe. I can give you the errors but it's a different error depending on which line I move the preprocessor statement to within the access_parameters block... so I was wondering if there was a certain order required or I've done something obviously wrong.

Comment: I posted an example in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a small example to create an `external table` using **PREPROCESSOR**. I did this on 12c:

```
SQL> select banner from v$version where rownum = 1;

BANNER
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> DROP TABLE validation_header;

Table dropped.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE validation_header (
  2  header1 VARCHAR2(5),
  3  header2 number,
  4  header3 VARCHAR2(8),
  5  header4 number
  6  )
  7  ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (
  8  TYPE oracle_loader
  9  DEFAULT DIRECTORY data_pump_dir
 10  ACCESS PARAMETERS (
 11  RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
 12  PREPROCESSOR import_ppm:'script.ksh'
 13  LOGFILE import_ppm:'script.log'
 14  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
 15  (header1,header2,header3, header4
 16  ))
 17  LOCATION ('script_file.txt')
 18  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

From the documentation,

> **KUP-04094: preprocessing cannot be performed if Database Vault is installed**
>
> - Cause: The Database Vault option did not permit the execution a program from an Oracle directory object.
> - Action: If preprocessing must be performed, then the Database Vault option must not be installed.

Comment: I guess it's an issue with our database then as I get the same issue with your example. SQL developer shows the red syntax error line at the beginning of the preprocessor line with the following error: KUP-04094: preprocessing cannot be performed if Database Vault is installed
29913. 00000 -  "error in executing %s callout"

Comment: Not good news then, we use data vault frequently for access so there's no chance of that going anywhere. I'll have to scrap preprocessor and do some pre processing in Perl or something before it gets to external tables.

Comment: Sounds a better workaround to do the preprocessing externally.